# How to create Thymeleaf button with image on it?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am creating my website https://github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/mysite_v2 (actually migrating from JSF to Spring MVC)
And want to create a button with image on it

```
<th:button type="button" th:image="@{/dist/images/ru32x32.png}" onclick="window.location.replace('?lang=ru');"/>
```

But it doesn't work. Image is not appears. In the same time image is here http://localhost:8080/dist/images/ru32x32.png displays well. Please teach me how to properly create button with image in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't know or care about images with buttons on them.  It only knows about HTML.

1. `<th:button />` isn't a valid HTML (or Thymeleaf) tag.  You should be using `<button />` here.
2. The [`<button />` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) does not have an attribute `image`.

If you want a button with an image, you should create the HTML you want and style it the way you want first, and then add the Thymeleaf if applicable.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.replace('?lang=ru');">
  <img th:src="@{/dist/images/ru32x32.png}" />
</button>
```